# Mongoose $lookup count references

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my simplified schema for my MongoDB database that I'm working on:

```
const podcastSchema: Schema = new Schema({
   name: { type: String, required: true },
   episodes: {
      type: [{
         title: { type: String, required: true },
      }],
      default: undefined
   }
},{
   timestamps: true
});
```

I've added a schema for stats, basically a listen count for each episode of the podcast:

```
const statisticSchema: Schema = new Schema({
   connectionIdentifier: { type: String, required: true },
   episode: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Podcast.Episodes' }
},{
   timestamps: true
});
```

Now I need to join (left outer join actually) for each episode in podcast the count of items in stats, so I can have something like this:

```
podcasts: {
   name: 'Lorem'
   episodes: [{
      title: 'Ipsum',
      played: 323
   },{
      title: 'Dolor',
      played: 12
   },
   ...
   ]
}
```

This is what I came from:

```
const episodes = await Podcast.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: podcastId } }, {
      $lookup: {
         from: 'statistics',
         localField: 'episodes._id',
         foreignField: 'episode',
         as: 'resultingEpisodeArray'
      }
   },{
      $unwind: { path: '$resultingEpisodeArray', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true }
   },{
      $group: {
         _id: null,
         episode: { $push: '$episodes' },
         played: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   },{
      $project: {
         _id: '$episode._id',
         title: '$episode.
         played: '$played'
      }
   }
]);
```

But it aggregate all podcast in a single one.
Where I'm failing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Where is `episodes._id` in `Podcast`? And you can simply use `$size` to count the number of elements in `resultingEpisodeArray`. Not sure why you used `$group` here?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, the _id is auto generated. I'll check your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AnthonyWinzlet suggestion, I got my errors. I really, really need to forget SQL when working on mongo.
For the sake of knowledge, here's the modified code that solved my issue:

```
const episodes = await Podcast.aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: podcastId } },
    { $unwind: '$episodes' },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'statistics',
            localField: 'episodes._id',
            foreignField: 'episode',
            as: 'resultingEpisodeArray'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: '$episodes._id',
            title: '$episodes.title',
            played: { $size: '$resultingEpisodeArray' }
        }
    },
]);
```

Again, kudos to Anthony for pointing me to the right direction!